# Using CSRF in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, csrf

Here is my CSRF as hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

And my csrf is generated as usual

While i am passing into route for a controller

Here is my old route

```
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@registeruser');
```

And to make it with csrf

```
Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{
    return 'You gave a valid CSRF token!';
}));
```

as per the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security)

While i routing it to the controller

```
Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf', RegisterController@registeruser()
{
    return 'You gave a valid CSRF token!';
}));
```

I am getting the error

```
syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should be this:

```
Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'RegisterController@registeruser');
```

Then you can handle it in your controller

```
class RegisterControllerextends Controller {

    protected function registeruser()
    {
        return 'You gave a valid CSRF token!';
    }

}
```

Comment: And may i use like this ? Route::get('view',array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'ViewController@view'));

Comment: You would not use CSRF for `GET` routes. Only POST, PUT and DELETE

Comment: And in raw php i use http referer validation, is it equivalent to this  ?if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == '') {header("Location: logout");}