# @csrf in laravel on include?

Tags: laravel, csrf

hope all is well.  I have been working on a laravel 7.4 project (planning to upgrade to 8 at some point) and just got to a point where I want to include a view within a view using the @include directive to include a login box.  To this end it worked as expected.  However, the @CSRF for these login fields now shows up as plain text, which I assume means it is not working.  I've done a bit of digging through the site and can't find this specific issue.  Some people ([Using CSRF in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749786/using-csrf-in-laravel)) recommend writing some controller code but the @csrf token works in the other forms I have created.  I am wondering if csrf is only required once per webpage and it is actually working or if something about the view inside a view throws this off.

For reference, here is loginBox.blade.php (pretty standard HTML form with @csrf)

```
<form method="POST">
      @csrf
      <p>Username:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="username">
      </p>
      <p>Password:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="password">
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
```

and in foo.blade.php:

```
@include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/loginBox.blade.php");
```

Again, the login box shows up fine so the right place is included but the @csrf is showing up as plaintext which is not an issue I have had with any of the other forms I have created.  Any advice or links in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
      <p>Username:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="username">
      </p>
      <p>Password:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="password">
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
```

Here is a link to how csrf tokens work and all that:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf